# Accessing Salesforce through two factor authentication

Tags: r

Trying to access Salesforce, and my Salesforce login requires a 2 factor authentication from my company's login email and requires a 2 factor authentication for Salesforce.

I have a token to get through SF's portion, but is there a way for me to incorporate one for my username email? For now, using the way below, it's telling me my login credentials are wrong.

```
library(RForcecom)
username <- "email@domain.com" 
password <- "password"
security_token <- "salesforce_security_token"
password.st <- paste0(password, security_token)
instanceURL <- "https://domain.my.salesforce.com"
apiVersion <- "41.0" 
session <- rforcecom.login(username, password.st, instanceURL, apiVersion)
```

I also tried to make the password var equal to the security token linked to my username-gmail account, but no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [**salesforcer**](https://github.com/StevenMMortimer/salesforcer) package supports OAuth2.0 authentication. It will cache your credentials so that you only need to use the interactive browser based part of the OAuth2.0 process on the very first time that you authenticate.

```
library(salesforcer)

# initiate OAuth2.0 login
sf_auth()

# check your Org and User info to confirm connection
user_info <- sf_user_info()
sprintf("Organization Id: %s", user_info$organizationId)
#> [1] "Organization Id: 00D6A0000003dN3UAI"
sprintf("User Id: %s", user_info$userId)
#> [1] "User Id: 0056A000000MPRjQAO"
```